# Values of points (x;y) as a grayscale image

Tags: matlab, grayscale

I am using matlab and I have two vectors with decimal values that are coordinates (`size(x)=size(y)=[1 98]`)

```
    x=[-4.5 -4.5 ... 4.5];
    y=[-4.5 -3.5 ... 4.5];

    plot(x,y,'+')
```

[image]

and I have a vector with decimal values for each of the points (`x;y`) (`size(v)=[98 1]`)

```
    v=[1.4350 ...].
```

Is there any way to plot my data as a grayscale image?

Comment: First of all you must reshape vector `v` in matrix form, using `reshape()` and then convert such matrix into a greyscale image using `mat2grey()`. Although seems that 2 points are missing (top of the plot), that will never allow you to create such matrix since a picture is a matrix of pixels and this matrix can either be rectangular or square.

Comment: the missing points need to be padded with zeros that's all; i.e. initiate your vectors using `zeros(100)`

Comment: the procedure then is pretty straightforward: 1) zero-pad the two missing points with 0; 2) reshape `v` in matrix form `V=reshape(v,10,10)`; 3) convert in grayscale `VGS=mat2gray(V)`; 4) display the image `figure; imshow(VGS);`

Comment: So `flipud( reshape(v, 10, 10) )` would do the trick to generate your image matrix when you add the missing two points as zeros within your vector `v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your data is not "square" so you can either:

1. Fill the two missing points somehow and then `imagesc(reshape(v,10,10))` plot it, or
2. Interpolate an image out of those points:

   `step=0.2; %//whatever you want
   [x1,y1]=meshgrid(-5:step:5,-5:step:5)
   img=interp2(x,y,v,x1,y1);
   imagesc(img);%// or imshow(img,[])`